# Where does the new Oxford-Birmingham airport bus stop in Birmingham

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, oxford, bhx

I've seen a number of adverts on bus stops around Oxford and on the sides of buses, for a new airline coach service to Birmingham. (There's already well-established ones from the same company, the Oxford Bus Company, for [Heathrow](https://airline.oxfordbus.co.uk/heathrow/) and [Gatwick](https://airline.oxfordbus.co.uk/gatwick/)).

These adverts have all mentioned that the coach serves both Birmingham International Airport and the NEC. However, those two things are separated by a major railway and some car parks! As such, you wouldn't want to be waiting at the wrong one...

So, where does the bus to Oxford actually leave from? The airport? The NEC? Other?

Comment: @pnuts I posted the question from onboard the bus! Wouldn't have found it with only the timetable though...

Answer (score 5):

This is [partly covered on the Oxford Bus Company website](https://airline.oxfordbus.co.uk/birmingham/). Having tried it today, the [map](https://assets.goaheadbus.com/media/cms_page_media/2721/airline-birmingham-airport-stops-July2016-4.1.png) isn't completely correct though...

The bus actually makes 3 stops in the NEC / Airport area. Heading towards Oxford, the first stop is from by the big new Resorts World building, by the lake outside the NEC. The bus doesn't stop at the main entrance, instead it stops at a bay round the back, furthest from the NEC, by the car parks. It leaves here very promptly, so I'm told by the driver who was surprised to find us there!

After that, it heads to the Birmingham International Airport station, via a lot of roundabouts. The stop here is on the airport side (west side) of the station, stand NB which is one of the ones furthest away from the station. That's a busy spot so it won't stop for long, make sure you're there in plenty of time too.

Finally, it goes round the corner to the Airport itself, and stops at Stand L, on your far left as you leave arrivals.

This map from the website has stops marked in approximately the right place, but it's a bit vague, and not quite accurate enough to find your stop easily, especially at Resorts World...
[image: Mostly accurate map from the Oxford Bus Company]

Comment: Could you add GPS coordinates in addition to the text descriptions? That would make it a lot easier to e.g. mark the spots on Google Maps.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not easily, I'm back in Oxford now having used the bus this afternoon!

Comment: @pnuts I don't think so - all the building work has finished, so it looked quite different yesterday compared to that 14 month old google streetview!